# Appengine email line wrapping

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm sending some text email in appengine. When I send using the development system (googleappenginelauncher 1.9.23 on a mac, python) things look fine. Long lines are formatted/wrapped by my email client.

When I deploy, though, the text is wrapped at ~80 characters. It's broken properly at work boundaries, so it's definitely happening on purpose. It's in the raw message, so it's not my client.

I can't find any reference to turning linebreaks on/off in the api and I haven't been able to find the place in the appengine code where it's even happening.

Any ideas?

thanks!

EDIT: The issue is with text email, like so:

```
    message = mail.EmailMessage()
    message.sender = _admin_email_address
    message.to = to
    message.subject = subject
    message.body = body

    try:
        message.send()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Failed to send mail {0} to {1}.\n{2}".format(subject, to, e))
        return False
```

The 'body' is just a hunk of text with its own internal linebreaks. When sent using the dev environment, the raw email shows the text with only its internal linebreaks; when deployed, though, extra linebreaks are added to keep the width to under 80 chars or so.

Comment: Are you send text or html emails?

Comment: Can u show your code snippet?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40122515/5320906 - mail  servers may be enforcing the RFC recommended 78 character/line limit.  Do you the wrapping in a mail client or when reading the mails programmatically?